# Matplotlib histogram appears, then disappears instantly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am working on the intro to pandas and I am stuck getting a histogram to appear from the set of data given.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

california_housing_dataframe = pandas.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")

california_housing_dataframe.hist('housing_median_age')
```

When I run the program an icon appears in my dock for just a quick second then disappears. Almost like the histogram was created but instantly closed out of.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script is probably closing after running it.

just add

```
raw_input()
```

at the end of your script